# Crash when reaching the end of executable

Tags: stm32, openocd

I have an executable that crashes after `main` has finished all its instructions, and the last assembler instruction is executed. Just before the program crashes, I do `disas` on GDB:

```
   0x2001c054 <+84>:    movt    r3, #16384      ; 0x4000
   0x2001c058 <+88>:    ldrh    r3, [r3, #16]
   0x2001c05a <+90>:    uxth    r3, r3
   0x2001c05c <+92>:    str     r3, [sp, #0]
   0x2001c05e <+94>:    bl      0x2001c0f8 <scream>
   0x2001c062 <+98>:    mov.w   r3, #0
   0x2001c066 <+102>:   mov     r0, r3
   0x2001c068 <+104>:   add     sp, #28
=> 0x2001c06a <+106>:   pop     {pc}
End of assembler dump.
```

Now if I go to the next instruction (`ni` in GDB) I get the following in GDB:

> 0xfffffffe in ?? ()

Also, OpenOCD (which I use to communicate with my STM32F2 board) gives the following error:

> Error: address + size wrapped(0xfffffffe, 0x00000004)

How can I tell my executable to exit gracefully?

Comment: You could use an infinite loop, or just set the controller in a wait state, better if standby or sleep mode

Comment: Yes, but that feels like a hack.

Comment: It's not a "hack". Do you think that Linux or Windows' kernels ever return from `main`? A program on a microcontroller (unless running under an existing OS) is more like an OS kernel. Never exit.

Comment: Yeah, Joby is right - that's how microcontrollers work.  Expand your mind man. It's a whole new world down here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this on a microcontroller?  If so, you should never exit main() - use an infinite loop instead.

Answer (score 5):

If this is an operating system or other app on the bare metal, `main` should never exit. If you really must exit, then your C startup code could reset the board after `main`.